# YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi video not playing when id passed from recycleview onClick listener

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

When I pass youtube ID from recycleview onClick then it shows "This video is unavailable". But same video id works fine when I hard code it. I tried every possible way but could not find any solution. Please, help if anyone can.
This is the code for sending video key,

```
intent.putExtra("vUrl", adListModel.getUrl());
```

Getting the video key,

```
vUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("vUrl");
```

Here, I am trying to load video from the video key,

```
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                String videoId = vUrl;
                Log.e("YOUTUBE_KEYS", videoId);
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
                youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                youTubePlayer.play();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post the sample code that you tried out too along with your question so that it makes it easy to help you out

Comment: updated with code

Comment: Check your Log.e statement for videoId received in both the cases.

Comment: 1. Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.
2. E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.
3. Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.

Comment: these are three error, i get whenever I start the activity.